# Datatables: Export Excel Formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, datatables

I'm having some issues when trying to format data when exporting to Excel using datatables. One of my columns contain a decimal point and displays OK when viewed in the browser as a table. When I export the table to excel this is rounding up the number in that column, this I do not want to happen. e.g shown in table '220419.07109' and when exported '220419.0711' I would prefer if this was just a string to maintain the full number.

```
  function formatDataForExport(data, row, column, node) {

    var string = data.toString();

    return string;


}

function drawDatatable(JSONData) {

    var dataSet = [];

    table = $("#div").DataTable({
        data: dataSet,
        columns: columns(),
        columnDefs: [{
             "targets": columnTargets(showConcludedColumns),
             "visible": false,
             "searchable": false
        }],
        info: false,
        searching: false,
        paging: false,
        ordering: false,
        autoWidth: true,
        responsive: true,
        buttons: [{
            extend: 'excel',
            text: "Export to Excel",
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ":visible",
                format: {
                    body: formatDataForExport
                }
            }
        }]
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following solution.

```
// Get the max value of an attribute of elements' list
var getMaxValue = function(elements, attr) {
    var values = elements.map(function(){
        return this.getAttribute(attr) || -Infinity;
    }).toArray();

    return Math.max.apply(Math, values);
}

$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    columns: [
        { data: 'Number' },
    ],
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            customize: function(xlsx) {
                //Get the built-in styles
                //refer buttons.html5.js "xl/styles.xml" for the XML structure
                var styles = xlsx.xl['styles.xml'];

                //Create a custom number format
                //Get the available id for the custom number format
                var numFmtId = getMaxValue($('numFmts numFmt', styles), 'numFmtId') + 1
                //XML Node: Custom number format for the timestamp column
                var nFmt = '<numFmt numFmtId="' + numFmtId + '" formatCode="0.######################"/>';
                // Add new node
                el = $('numFmts', styles);
                el.append(nFmt).attr('count', parseInt(el.attr('count'))+1);
                //Create our own style to use the custom number format above
                //XML Node: Custom style for the timestamp column
                var style = '<xf numFmtId="' + numFmtId + '" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" applyBorder="1" xfId="0" applyNumberFormat="1"/>';
                // Add new node
                el = $('cellXfs', styles);
                el.append(style).attr('count', parseInt(el.attr('count'))+1);
                // Index of our new style
                var styleIdx = $('xf', el).length - 1;

                //Apply new style to the first (A) column
                var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                //Set new style default for the column (optional)
                $('col:eq(0)', sheet).attr('style', styleIdx);
                //Apply new style to the existing rows of the first column ('A'), skipping header row
                $('row:gt(0) c[r^="A"]', sheet).attr('s', styleIdx);
            },
        },
    ]
} );
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsmcan/3dj5oat6/)

You could use different kinds of formatting there:

- *0.######################* - will show as many digits after decimal point as you have "#";
- *#.######################* - the same as above, but with no 0 in a number like 0.1234;
- *0.??????????????????????* - the same as above, but aligned by the decimal point

Simplified version, the resulted file opens correctly in Excel, but the shortcuts could affect other XLSX files reading software: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsmcan/fk321za9/)